# Bootstrap popover with knockout.js

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I've got an application receiving some data through AJAX-call. After that, received data binds to DOM-elements using *knockout.js* library. I'd like to use boostrap's unobtrusive markup for creating popovers like this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td><b data-bind="text: $data.id"></b></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.title"></td>
        <td><a href="#" rel="popover" data-bind="attr: {title: $data.info}" data-placement="top">Info</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

According to the latest *bootstrap* documentation, implicit call of something like `$('.popover').popover()` isn't required, however, it's not working.

I suppose, that *boostrap.js* perform some DOM-analysis on document.ready and perform all needed work for popover to work. And the question: is there some way to tell *bootstrap.js* to perform similar job for data after receiving AJAX response? Or how this kind of requirements can be achieved?

Comment: Yes, I think that bootstrap's implicit binding works only for elements present on DOM ready.
Can't you just add `$('.popover').popover()` in your ajax's success callback?

Comment: @Ingro, yes this is the simplest way, but in my opinion implementing custom data binding is the better way (as Luffy did below)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can create custom dataBinding to make that element popover. Check this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/dyXT7/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapPopover = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var defaultOptions = {};        
        options = $.extend(true, {}, defaultOptions, options);
        $(element).popover(options);
    }
};

var viewModel = {

    items: ko.observableArray([{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "title-1",
        "info": "info-1"},
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "title-2",
        "info": "info-2"},
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "title-3",
        "info": "info-3"}])

}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

And html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">     
        <table class="table table-condensed" data-bind="foreach: items">
            <tr>
                <td><b data-bind="text: $data.id"></b></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.title"></td>
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="bootstrapPopover : {content : $data.info  }">Info</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful though I think we could also pass content and header attributes to the `bootstrapPopover` binding to make it clearer

Comment: Is the fiddle supposed to do something?

Comment: Yep. Click the info link and observe the popover. I guess info text doesnt show up immediately. Scroll right to reach the info link :)

Comment: Decrease the width size you can see easily now.

Comment: Works like a charm! How can i assing "hover" and "click" as triggers to this?

Answer (score 7):

> "According to the latest bootstrap documentation, implicit call of something like $('.popover').popover() isn't required, however, it's not working."

I can't find anywhere in the docs that states that. In fact, they state quite the opposite.  Namely, Twitter Bootstrap does **not** automatically initialize popovers or tooltips on a page.  [From the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers):

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt in.
>   If you would like to use them just specify a selector option.

In order to "opt in", as they say, you would attach the Popover object to an element which contains all the popovers which might appear on the page.  Here's one way of doing it:

```
$('body').popover({selector: '[rel="popover"]'});
```

I believe the performance considerations originally in mind came from the fact that prior to 2.1, the Popover plugin was by default triggered by **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events, which are certainly not something you want to be constantly processing for an entire page.

Since 2.1, the default is now **click**, which shouldn't pose any performances issues.  Nevertheless, if you can determine an element farther down the DOM than `body` to which to attach the Popover object, that is always preferred.  However, depending on where you are displaying the AJAX content, `body` might be your best bet.

Comment: Actually, if you check the doc page source code you'll find out that example given there is implemented with that very data-apis only.

Comment: @koss You seem to have overlooked the **application.js** file. In there is the code which initializes the popover demo on the page: `$("a[rel=popover]").popover().click(function(e) {e.preventDefault()})`.

Comment: Yes I missed it, and that cause a lot of confusion for me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The problem solved, the mysteries clarified!

Comment: Excellent explanation of the reason for the "opt-in" nature of popover & tooltip. Thanks @merv

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working example with array of objects, I changed the `ko.applyBindings()` to `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants` to include the binding context $root and $parent when we would like to associate a button for example to a function in a root viewModel.

```
$(element).click(function() {
            $(this).popover('toggle');
            var thePopover = document.getElementById(attribute.id+"-popover");
            childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(viewModel);
            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, thePopover);
    });
```

Take a look @ http://jsfiddle.net/mounir/Mv3nP/6/