# Twitter Bootstrap Popover with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I am trying to get Bootstrap popovers to work on dynamic content. I have a jQuery AJAX request that returns some rows of data. The AJAX success function will loop through and generate HTML code from the retrieved data. The generated HTML has the Bootstrap code in it but it doesn't work. If I just write the HTML code normally, it works fine.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do. newRowReg just loops through each record retrieved and appends it to the HTML string.

```
newRowReg += "<tr>";
newRowReg += "<td>" + xStatus + "</td>";
newRowReg += "<td><img src='green dotx.jpg' class='ppt1' data-container='body' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='right' data-content='Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.'>";
newRowReg += "</tr>";
$("#regTbl").append(newRowReg);
```

The Javascript code for the popup.

```
$('.ppt1').popover({
    title: 'Title 1',
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: 'Some Content!'
  });
```

How do I get this to work when it's generated dynamically like this?

Comment: This might have been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140491/bootstrap-popover-with-knockout-js . Except he is using event handlers. I would just call the popover function again after ajax success.

Comment: The popover function is called after the AJAX.

Comment: @zer02 - I checked through the link you suggested. I'm new at jQuery and Bootstrap so I didn't understand how to apply that advice to my situation. Can anyone help with my case? 

How do I get Popovers to work with HTML that is appended after a page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a link like this

```
<a href="#" id="show_media" class="btn btn-small btn-info" 
                            rel="popover" 
                            value="{{ $value->id }}"
                            data-content="<div id='div{{ $value->id }}'></div><script>loadMedia({{ $value->id }})</script>" 
                            data-original-title="My Title">Show Media</a>
```

Then before the body ends

```
  <script>  
    $(function (){ 
        $("#show_media").popover({placement: 'top', html: true});
    }); 
    function loadMedia(adsId){
        console.log("Ads ID: " +adsId);
        $('div#div' + adsId).html('xxxx');
    } 
    </script>
```