# Bootstrap popover inside a data bound context

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am having some trouble getting a popover to work inside a knockout data bound context.  Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/html" id="random-template">
<button id="Howdy" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
        data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-trigger="focus">
    Popover on left
</button>
<h3>Some Detail</h3>
<div data-bind="with: someDetail">

    <buttonid id="Hello" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
              data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-trigger="focus">
        Popover on left
    </buttonid>
```

The button with id="Howdy" has a popover that works.  The button inside the knockout databound context "with" does not.  I am guessing my issue is with my data-container, I am just not sure.  The ultimate goal is to get this to work with a text input in that same section.

Here is the js function if it helps:

```
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140491/bootstrap-popover-with-knockout-js

Comment: you'll need to initialize the popover after the data is available, or create a custom binding handler like in the linked SO answer above

Comment: Thanks.  I was searching all over stack overflow and couldn't find an answer.  I think I was probably wording my search incorrectly since I am still new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd button tag is wrong : just replace :

```
<buttonid="Hello" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
          data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-trigger="focus">
    Popover on left
</buttonid>
```

with :

```
<button id="Hello" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
          data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-trigger="focus">
    Popover on left
</button>
```

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/9n3wujc3/1/